# replace english quotes to german quotes

Tags: php, internationalization, replace

is there a way to implement german quotes (so-called 'Gänsefüßchen')

```
&bdquo; („) and &ldquo; (“)
```

in a function to convert english-quoted strings like

> I say "Hallo"

to

> I say „Hallo“

the &bdquo should only apply at the beginning, the &ldquo at the end of an string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the function, tested and works fine.

**Note:** the &bdquo applies **only** at the beginning, the &rdquo only at the end of an string. *(hsz's solution isn't following that rule)*

```
function germanquotes($text){
    $size = strlen($text);
    $i=0;
    $replace = array();
    $replace['one'] = array();
    $replace['two'] = array();
    while($i < $size)
    {
        if($text[$i] == '"')
        {
            if($text[$i-1] == " " || empty($text[$i-1]))
            {
                    $replace['one'][] = $i;
            }
            elseif($text[$i+1] == " " || empty($text[$i+1]))
            {
                $replace['two'][] = $i;
            }
        }

        $i++;
    }

    $y = 0;
    $it = 0;
    foreach($replace['one'] as $ghh)
    {
        $text = substr_replace($text, '&bdquo;', ($ghh+$y), 1);
        $y += 6;
        $it++;
    }

    $to=0;
    $i=1;
    $u=1;
    foreach($replace['two'] as $ghhd)
    {
        $text = substr_replace($text, '&rdquo;', ($ghhd-1+$to+((8*$i)-($u*1))), 1);
        $i++;
        $u +=2;
        $to +=6;
    }

    return $text;
}
```

Test:

```
echo(germanquotes('I am "glad" to write "functions" for "stackoverflow" users'));
```

Comment: :D echo(germanquotes('Me too that you are, as it works "über-fine"!'));

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
$input  = 'I say "Hallo".';
$output = preg_replace('/"(.*?)"/', '„$1“', $input);
```

It replaces all even amount of quotes into `„“`.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the replacement "state" you are in. First you always replace a quote with `&bdquo`, then you set a flag and if that flag is true, you replace a quote with `&rdquo` and then you turn the flag off. Repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it also with CSS property [quotes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_gen_quotes.asp):

```
quotes: "„" "“" "‚" "‘";
```

[Example](http://dret.net/css-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you always have a space infront of the " you want to replace you could do it like this

> str_replace (' \"', ' „', $input);

Comment: but the answer above is better ;)