# Replace every second occurrence of quotes in NSString (iOS NSString)

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I need to replace the standard upper double quotes "" that already exist (in text I get from a database) with specific quotes for german text for use in a UIWebView.
The first double quote character before the quoted word(s) (every even index) needs to be replaced with the HTML equivalent of „ which is `&bdquo;` and the second one after the quoted word(s) (every odd index) with “ which is `&ldquo;`. The quotes can be anywhere in the text, so I can't rely on any fixed positions.

So basically I have a NSString like this:

*just "some" text with some "more" text*

or in Objective-C:

```
NSString *str = @"just \"some\" text with some \"more\" text";
```

I am aware of the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString method from NSString, but of course this only replaces all double quotes with the bottom double quote mark.

```
NSString *newStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"&bdquo;"];
```

I couldn't find a way to just replace every second or every n-th occurrence, does someone have a hint/idea how I could accomplish that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Here's same issue + solution for PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224893/replace-english-quotes-to-german-quotes . You should be able to translate it to objC.

Comment: you can replace every  `<Space>"` with `<Space>„`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSScanner` offers another option...

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:englishString];
NSMutableString *germanString = [NSMutableString string];
BOOL foundQuote = YES;
int quoteIndex = 0;

while (foundQuote) {
    NSString *nextPart = @"";
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"\"" intoString:&nextPart];
    if (nextPart != nil) {
        [germanString appendString:nextPart];
    }
    foundQuote = [scanner scanString:@"\"" intoString:nil];
    if (foundQuote) {
        [germanString appendString:((quoteIndex % 2) ? @"&ldquo;" : @"&bdquo;")];
        quoteIndex++;
    }
}

NSLog(@"The German version is: %@", germanString);
```

Comment: thanks, I went with this solution as it seemed the most straightforward to me (I added a missing ampersand before "bdquo;") - works perfect

Comment: btw one minor improvement: if you initialize NSString *nextPart; with an empty string NSString *nextPart = @""; it's also possible to detect double quotation marks at the first position in the text, otherwise my app freezes without an error code..

Comment: @hajn Sounds good. I've added that, but you should feel free to edit answers with simple improvements like that if you want to. Users helping to refine answers is one of the things that makes SO work well.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should be a push in the right direction:

```
static NSString * StringByReplacingEverySecondOccurrenceWithString(
                        NSString * const pSource,
                        NSString * const pSearch,
                        NSString * const pReplace)
{
  /* @todo test that pSource has two occurrences before copying, and return [pSource.copy autorelease] if false. */
  NSMutableString * const str = [pSource.mutableCopy autorelease];
  bool isEven = true;
  for (NSUInteger pos = 0; pos < str.length; isEven = !isEven) {
    const NSRange remainder = NSMakeRange(pos, str.length - pos);
    const NSRange next = [str rangeOfString:pSearch options:0 range:remainder];
    if (NSNotFound != next.location && !isEven) {
      [str replaceCharactersInRange:next withString:pReplace];
    }
    pos = next.location + next.length;
  }
  return [str.copy autorelease];
}
```

---

**Update**

and if you want to follow Caleb's edit to the question, you can use this to alternate substituted strings:

```
static NSString * StringByReplacingWithAlternatingStrings(
                          NSString * const pSource,
                          NSString * const pSearch,
                          NSString * const pReplaceA,
                          NSString * const pReplaceB)
{
  /* @todo test that pSource has two occurrences before copying, and return [pSource.copy autorelease] if false. */
  NSMutableString * const str = [pSource.mutableCopy autorelease];
  bool isEven = true;
  for (NSUInteger pos = 0; pos < str.length; isEven = !isEven) {
    const NSRange remainder = NSMakeRange(pos, str.length - pos);
    const NSRange next = [str rangeOfString:pSearch options:0 range:remainder];
    if (NSNotFound != next.location) {
      NSString * const substitution = isEven ? pReplaceA : pReplaceB;
      [str replaceCharactersInRange:next withString:substitution];
      pos = next.location + substitution.length;
    }
    else {
      pos = NSNotFound;
    }
  }
  return [str.copy autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using regular expressions then.

```
NSString *str = @"just \"some\" text with some \"more\" text";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\"(\\w+)\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) withTemplate:@"\"$1&quote"];
NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 NSString *string = @"just \"some\" text with some \"more\" text";
 NSArray *arr = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
 NSMutableString *formattedResponse = [NSMutableString string];
 for (int i = 0;i<[arr count];i++)//(NSString *str in arr)
 {
    if(i == 0)
    {
        [formattedResponse appendString:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    else{
    if(i%2 == 0)
    {
        [formattedResponse appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    else{
        [formattedResponse appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@,,",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]]; // replace downward quotes as i don't know
    }
    }
 }
 NSLog(@"formattedResponse : %@",formattedResponse);
```