# Replacing all english quotes with german quotes

Tags: javascript, quotes, quotation-marks

im here to ask, if someone can help me with quotation and syntax checking.
im aware of the question [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224893/replace-english-quotes-to-german-quotes), but i don't fully understand that solution.

here is an example, fully integrated into a website and humbly ask, if anyone can find an error?

```js
function rewriteQuotes(){
  var all_p = document.querySelectorAll(`.content_container`);
  var regex_s = /[\s\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#$%&()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~]/;
  for (var i = 0; i < all_p.length; i++) {
    if (all_p[i] != null) {
      var all_nodes = all_p[i].querySelectorAll("*");
      for (var k = 0; k < all_nodes.length; k++) {
        if (all_nodes[k].childNodes.length > 0) {
          var all_children = all_nodes[k].childNodes;
          for (var t = 0; t < all_children.length; t++) {
            if (all_children[t].nodeName == "#text") {
              all_children[t].textContent = all_children[t].textContent.replace(/"/g,"\“");
              all_children[t].textContent = all_children[t].textContent.replace(/\s\“/g,"\ „");
              if (all_children[t].textContent.charAt(0)== "\“") {
                if (all_children[t].textContent.charAt(1) === "") {
                } else {
                  var char_1 = all_children[t].textContent.charAt(1);
                  if (regex_s.test(char_1)) {
                  } else {
                    all_children[t].textContent = "\„" + all_children[t].textContent.substring(1);
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    rewriteQuotes();
  },1);
});
```

```html
<div class="content_container">
  <h2>"Hello"</h2>
  <p>my "aunti" was driving over the "cat" with her "<em>skateboard</em>".</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your regex and capture groups of `"..."` and then replace the quotes of those groups with your desired ones:

```js
const regex = /"(.*?)"/g;
const str = `my "aunti" was driving over the "cat" with her "car"`;
const subst = `„$1“`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log('Original: ', str);
console.log('Result: ', result);
```

Comment: @Rainer: Any feedback?

Comment: this looks like a very nice solution, but when there are some quotes inside some emphasis or like that, i need to work around that situation. But i thank you for your look into it, it helps me alot!

Comment: I think you basically just need to get all text contents of each element you want to replace quotes in, and then apply above code. If you like you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left, if my answer was helpful. Thanks :)